# Is this space sequentially compact?

Tags: general-topology

I have to show that the topological space $(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$ with $\mathcal{T}=\{U\subset\mathbb{Z}| (n\in U \Leftrightarrow -n\in U)\,\, \forall n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is sequentially compact, but I don't think it is. I considered the sequence $(n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Which convergent subsequence does it have? To what does it converge? Might there be a mistake in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, as posed, the space is not sequentially compact, and your sequence has no convergent subsequence. But can you actually prove it?

Comment: Well, there is no point to which a subsequence would converge. Suppose there was a $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a_{n_k}:=(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $z$. Then for every open neighborhood $U$ of $z$ there would be an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{n_k}\in U$ for all $k\ge N$. But take for example $U=\{-z,z\}$ then even the very next element of the sequence is not an element of $U$, because $(a_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ must be strictly montonically increasing just as $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: @mathemagician99 Yes, that's correct. In fact, $\{-z, z\}$ is the smallest neighborhood of every $z ∈ ℤ$. This spaces is essentially just countable discrete space where all points but $0$ are “doubled”.